# How to return NULL results when using "WHERE" on a joined date?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `users`

```
userid | first | last | active |...
1      | John  | Doe  | Yes    |...
2      | Jane  | Doe  | Yes    |...
3      | Jack  | Smith| Yes    |...
```

and `time_sheet`

```
timesheetid | userid | status | weekStart | lastVisited | ...
1           | 1      | Created| 2022-10-10| DATETIME    | ...
2           | 2      | Created| 2022-10-03| DATETIME    | ...
```

I am trying to get all users timesheets in a given week. My current query is:

```
SELECT x.first, x.last, a.lastVisited,
CASE 
  WHEN a.status IS NULL THEN "Not Created"
  ELSE a.status
END as status
FROM users x
LEFT OUTER JOIN time_sheet a ON x.userid = a.userid
WHERE x.active = "Yes" AND (a.weekStart = "2022-10-10" OR a.weekStart IS NULL);
```

Which fails because, when a user has a timesheet on a previous or later date, they do not show up in the result.

ie: I have 28 users, 2 users have timesheets that are not on `weekStart` = "2022-10-10" and 1 User with time sheet on `weekStart` "2022-10-10". That one user and every user who have not created a time sheet on a previous date will show in the result giving 26 rows returned.

So my question is: Am I able to filter by date but also list null results for when there is no record in the specified "joined" date?

So in my example above I would only get a row for "John Doe" and "Jack Smith" BUT I would not get a record for "Jane Doe" with "Not Created" which is what im trying to achieve

or

```
John Doe   | Created
Jack Smith | Not Created
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just figured out you can add the date to the `ON` clause and this works for me:

```
SELECT x.first, x.last, a.lastVisited,
CASE 
  WHEN a.status IS NULL THEN "Not Created"
  ELSE a.status
END as status
FROM users x
LEFT OUTER JOIN time_sheet a ON x.userid = a.userid AND a.weekStart = "2022-10-10"
WHERE x.active = "Yes";
```

Although a better explanation for why this changes the results would be appreciated

Comment: I hope the "rules" in my Answer will help you next time you struggle with `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: It changes the results because the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is going to return `NULL` values for the rows it couldn't find a match for in the `time_sheet` table. When you filter on a field from the `time_sheet` table, e.g. `a.weekStart = "2020-10-10"` via the `WHERE` clause, `NULL` does not equal `2020-10-10`, and therefore those entire rows get filtered. When you move that predicate from the `WHERE` clause to the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` clause, it doesn't filter out rows (because it's an outer join) rather it just makes less rows match from the `time_sheet` table, but retains all the rows from `users`.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this (assuming it gives the 'correct' results):

```
SELECT  x.first, x.last, a.lastVisited, 
        COALESCE(a.status, "Not Created") as status
    FROM  users x
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  time_sheet a  ON x.userid = a.userid
    WHERE  x.active = "Yes";
      AND  a.weekStart = "2022-10-10"
```

Rules for a `LEFT JOIN`:

- Use `ON` for how the tables are related.  In your tables, one user has many time_sheets.  This will produce more rows than ultimately desired; keep reading...
- Use `WHERE` to "filter".  That is, say which rows you want to keep.  You want only active users and only timesheets for Oct 10.

The Optimizer is free to move clauses between `ON` and `WHERE`.  There are no restrictions for `INNER JOIN`.  There are some restrictions on `ON`.  I give the two rules above so that *humans* will understand the *intent*.

(While I was at it, I use `COALESCE` simply because it was fewer keystrokes.)

(The keywords `INNER`, `OUTER`, and `CROSS` are ignored by MySQL; the `ON` and `WHERE` clauses provide the real meaning.)

Comment: Ok your rules provide some much needed clarity. I think the error with that query then is that it filters only to Oct 10 records and thus doesn't produce "Not Created" rows since they don't match the filter, correct? I only get one row returned when executing the code above